# Find out who is executing the stored procedure from within said procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Am I able to find out who is executing the stored procedure from within that procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @executor 
    SET @executor = {query to find out}
END
```

Comment: Try `SET @executor = ORIGINAL_LOGIN();`

Comment: In many cases there isn't an informative "who" available. For example, a website is likely to use a single connect string to access a database. Getting the SQL user won't tell you anything about who is using the website, whether they authenticated, ... .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can use functions like

- `SUSER_NAME()` Function (*it returns the login identification name of the  user*) [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx)
- `CURRENT_USER()` (*it returns the name of the current user*) [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050.aspx)
- `USER_NAME()` (*it returns a database user name from a specified identification number*) [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188014.aspx)
- `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` (*it Returns the name of the login that connected to the instance of SQL Server.*) [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189492.aspx)

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @executor 
    SELECT @executor = SUSERNAME()
    ...
END
```

You can read more in this very useful articles:

- [Functions That Return User Names and User IDs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191126(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Difference between ORIGINAL_LOGIN and SUSER_NAME](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/07/28/sql-server-difference-between-original_login-and-suser_sname/)